# first check the array if exist update it else push

Tags: php, arrays

```
   for($j=0;$j<count($data);$j++)   {for($i = $begin; $begin <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')){
            $totaldistance=0;
            $totalorder=0;
            for($j=0;$j<count($data);$j++)  {
                $unixtime_=$data[$j]['create_date'];
                $distance=$data[$j]['distance'];
                $distance=$data[$j]['distance'];
                //$orginal_time= substr($unixtime_,0,10);
                $start_date_orignal=date_format(date_create($unixtime_),'Y-m-d');
                //echo '<br>';
                if($i->format("Y-m-d") == $start_date_orignal){ 
                    $totaldistance=$totaldistance+$distance;
                    $totalorder=$totalorder+1;
                    $wholedata1[]=array('start_date_orignal'=>$start_date_orignal,'totaldistance'=>$totaldistance,'totalorder'=>$totalorder);
                    echo "<pre>";
                    echo $i->format("Y-m-d").'='.$start_date_orignal.'='.$totaldistance.'='.$totalorder;
                    echo "</pre>";
                     if(in_array($start_date_orignal,$wholedata)){
                        echo "sasa";
                    }else{
                        echo "1221";
                        array_push($wholedata,array('start_date_orignal'=>$start_date_orignal,'totaldistance'=>$totaldistance,'totalorder'=>$totalorder));
                    }   
                }

            }

        }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-05-23
                [totaldistance] => 0
                [totalorder] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-05-23
                [totaldistance] => 0
                [totalorder] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-05-23
                [totaldistance] => 0
                [totalorder] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-05-23
                [totaldistance] => 0
                [totalorder] => 4
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-05-23
                [totaldistance] => 0
                [totalorder] => 5
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-05-23
                [totaldistance] => 0
                [totalorder] => 6
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-06-17
                [totaldistance] => 29.8
                [totalorder] => 1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-06-18
                [totaldistance] => 1
                [totalorder] => 1
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-06-18
                [totaldistance] => 1
                [totalorder] => 2
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-06-18
                [totaldistance] => 1
                [totalorder] => 3
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-06-18
                [totaldistance] => 1
                [totalorder] => 4
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [start_date_orignal] => 2016-06-18
                [totaldistance] => 1.1
                [totalorder] => 5
            )

    )
```

So I have a end and start date and a array data which have my query data . As you can see my output I am getting **start_date_orignal as key and his value 2016-05-23** . I am getting this value 5 times , so I want when the same date already exist it will update the totalorder and totalcount of that particular date . so plz can anyone help me

Comment: I don't know where the data comes from, but if it is a database, you should probably do that there already.

Comment: yes it is coming from database only but this a report page , that's why i am checking for every date and getting a total count and total distance count

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments: you probably want to include this in your query. Since you haven't posted your SQL I'll have to guess, but it will look something like this:

```
SELECT
start_date_original, SUM(totaldistance) as totaldistance, SUM(totalorder) as totalorder
FROM `table`
GROUP BY start_date_original
```

Take a look at [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate
>   functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

### Edit:

If however you really want to do this in a php loop, I'd suggest something like this:

```
<?php
function cmp( $a, $b ) {
    if ( $a['start_date_original'] == $b['start_date_original'] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a['date'] < $b['date'] ) ? - 1 : 1;
}

usort( $data, "cmp" );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $data ); $i ++ ) {
    if ( $data[ $i ]['date'] !== $data[ $i + 1 ]['date'] ) {
        continue; # No duplicate.
    }

    # We found a duplicate, so we'll add the current items to the next one. Then unset this one.
    $data[ $i + 1 ]['totaldistance'] += $data[ $i ]['totaldistance'];
    $data[ $i + 1 ]['totalorder'] += $data[ $i ]['totalorder'];

    unset($data[$i]);
}
```

We're doing two things here:

1. Sort the array on date.
2. Sum duplicates -- which are now conveniently located next to each other.

Your array may already sort the result on date, if that's the case you can remove the `usort()`.

---

I still think summing in your query is a better idea.

Comment: I can't change my query because I am getting lot of data acc to result page filters , I just need to fix this when i get a duplicate date then it will update the other two keys value else just push the new data \